# Setting all columns to zero if one is zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with 4 columns. For some rows all columns have entries > 0, but for others some columns are zero. Depending on the value of a variable set_average I would like to set the columns containing zero to the average of the non-zero columns (if set_average == True) or I want to set all non-zero columns to zero (if set_average == False), but only if there's one zero column in that row. How can I do this? It seems that I have the case figured out where I set the zero columns to the average of the non-zero ones:

```
df['average'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df['notzero'] = df.astype(bool).sum(axis=1)
df['average'] = df['average']/df['notzero']
if set_average == True: 
    df = df[df!=0].fillna(df['average'])
```

But I can't figure out how to do the second case. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: please detail more if you are looking to fill zero or null, your title says null, you speak about zero and then use `fillna()`

Comment: I mean zero = 0.